# Gitlab node_modules in .gitignore, how to still edit and push a module

Tags: reactjs, react-native, github, gitlab

I have node_modules in .gitignore.
Now I changed a module (Searchbar from reactnativeelements).
Whats the best and cleanest way to still push it to my gitlab?
A seperate folder, where I put the complete module and change all imports gets me somehow the Error: `Invariant Violation: No callback found with cbID 750 and callID 375 for module <unknown>. Args: '["{\"codeFrame\":{\"content\":\"\\u001b[0m \\u001b[90m 20 |\\u001b[39m \\u001b[36mvar\\u001b[39m ba\\u001b[33m=\\u...(truncated)..."]'`
Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get error, because changes in node_modules folder ignored by git (it's normal).

You can use `patch-package` https://github.com/ds300/patch-package for change npm modules and save this changes in project.